# Can't get Jinja2 working with django 1.9

Tags: django, jinja2

If I install as suggested in django 1.9 docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2) 
with two items in TEMPLATES, the first is the jinja2 backend, the second is the django backend:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'DIRS': [

        PROJECT_ROOT+ "/templates/jinja",

        ],
    'APP_DIRS' : True,

     'OPTIONS': {
        'environment': 'commshub.jinja2_settings.environment',
    },
},

{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        PROJECT_ROOT+ "/templates",
        ],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'debug': DEBUG,
        'context_processors': [
            "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
            "django.core.context_processors.debug",
            "django.core.context_processors.media",
            'django.core.context_processors.request',
            'django.core.context_processors.static',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

        ],
    },
},
```

]

but WITHOUT 'environment' setting, then appears to work provided I remove also 'auto_reload' setting for both jinja and django, otherwise get

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_reload'
```

If I add myproj.jinja2.py with content as shown in django docs, still no 'environment' option, I get:

```
 cannot import name Environment
```

If I change "from jinja2 import Environment" to ""from jinja2.environment import Environment"

```
  No module named environment
```

In light of this post, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/pytjLOVUwmM/gbiDmswSuq4J,  I try renaming jinja2.py  to jinja2_settings.py and add this TEMPLATE options:

```
 'environment': 'jinja2_settings.environment', -> pop() takes no arguments (2 given)

 'environment': 'myproj.jinja2_settings.environment', -> No module named commshub.jinja2_settings
```

Tried removing django backend altogether but got the same error as above.

Not sure what else to try!

Comment: If you are using Python 2, make sure you have included the `from __future__ import absolute_import` line from the docs. If you forget to include it, your `jinja2.py` module might clash with the `from jinja2 import Environment` import.

Comment: Alasdair, Yes copied the example exactly from the django 1.9 docs that includes the import.